# Paypal REST API invalid credentials

Tags: api, paypal

I use the REST api in my nodejs application.
All is working good with sandbox but when i update with live credentials i get:

```
{ [Error: Response Status : 401]
  response:
   { error: 'invalid_client',
     error_description: 'The client credentials are invalid',
     httpStatusCode: 401 },
  httpStatusCode: 401 }
```

I updated my account to buisness but still not working, i use the live endpoint and Live credentials.

What should i do in order to make this work?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue using PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-nodejs and solved passing with the configuration parameters (host, client_id, client_secret, ...) also the parameter '**mode**' set to '**live**'. Otherwise the default mode used by the library is 'sandbox' and hence the impossibility to use the live credentials.

Comment: Thanks, helped with the mode bit. just to clarify in the paypal.configure() function you need to pass in {mode: "live"} (as well as your credentials in the same object)

Comment: after reading and looking at all the documentation paypal (over 2000 pages) and never found a solution. Gentlemen thanks for the very simple answer

Answer (score 0):

As matteo said, if you switch from dev to live environment, only updateing the client id and secret isn't enough. You need to set the ApiContext-Mode to "live".

PayPals PHP REST-API-SDK comes with some great samples. Take a look at the bootstrap.php in /vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/ in line 84. There are some configurations happening, after getting the api context.

```php
<?php

$apiContext = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        $clientId,
        $clientSecret
    )
);

// Comment this line out and uncomment the PP_CONFIG_PATH
// 'define' block if you want to use static file
// based configuration

$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG', // PLEASE USE `INFO` LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
        'cache.enabled' => true,
        // 'http.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' => 30
        // 'http.headers.PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id' => '123123123'
        //'log.AdapterFactory' => '\PayPal\Log\DefaultLogFactory' // Factory class implementing \PayPal\Log\PayPalLogFactory
    )
);
```