# Make payment using paypal and NodeJS

Tags: paypal

I'd like to make payment using NodeJS and PayPal API but it doesn't work because my app that I created is using Sandbox and not live...

How to use PayPal live ?

My JSON config :

```js
{
  "api" : {
    "host" : "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
    "port" : "",
    "client_id" : "*****",
    "client_secret" : "*****"
  },
  "returnUrl" : "http://localhost:3000/returnurl",
  "cancelUrl" : "http://localhost:3000/order/user/"
}
```

My NodeJS code :

```js
this.paypal.configure(paypalConfigs.api);

var payment = {
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": paypalConfigs.returnUrl,
    "cancel_url": paypalConfigs.cancelUrl+request.user.id
  },
  "transactions": [{
    "amount": {
      "total": total,
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "description": "Commande Printwithlove"
  }]
};

paypal.payment.create(payment, function (error, payment) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    if(payment.payer.payment_method === 'paypal') {
      request.session.paymentId = payment.id;
      var redirectUrl;
      for(var i=0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
        var link = payment.links[i];
        if (link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
          redirectUrl = link.href;
        }
      }
      response.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
  }
});
```

And my app on PayPal :

[image]

Edit :

```js
[**.fr.3008-13 (out)] { [Error: Response Status : 401]
[**.fr.3008-13 (out)]   response: 
[**.fr.3008-13 (out)]    { error: 'invalid_client',
[**.fr.3008-13 (out)]      error_description: 'The client credentials are invalid',
[**.fr.3008-13 (out)]      httpStatusCode: 401 },
[**.fr.3008-13 (out)]   httpStatusCode: 401 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change that you need to do while going from sandbox to live is to change the endpoint from " api.sandbox.paypal.com" to " api.paypal.com" and use the live credentials from the developer.paypal.com

Comment: I get error to, msg: "The client credentials are invalid" when use live credential

Comment: check this question for some solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472594/paypal-rest-api-invalid-credentials)